# Samsung NP530U3C hdd upgrade

Tags: laptop

I am about to buy myself a 13"3 Samsung NP530UC ultrabook but the 500 GB (5400rpm) hdd + 16 GB SSD combo just freaks me out. I was wondering if there is a possibility to upgrade that to a single SSD (128GB would be enough).

Is it possible to do that ?

Comment: Why does it freak you out?  It should help boot times if nothing else.

Comment: I'd much rather change it to full ssd drive, but i'm not sure this model supports such changes

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to do that. All you'd have to do is pull out the SATA HDD, and replace it with with a new SATA SSD.

As for the existing 16gb SSD - it's most likely mSata. You have multiple options. You can just pull it out and sell it on ebay or something. Or you could span it with Windows Disk Manager. In my case I used it as a giant page file.